# toggle not holding active

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two slider menus, left and right, and only right is holding the active value when it is clicked. Left menu only slides out when the toggle button is held down, and i need to it slide when the toggle is clicked not just held down.

```js
$('.leftToggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".sidebarleft").toggleClass("sidebarleftactive");
});
```

```css
/*sidebar left*/

.sidebarleft {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0px;
  left: auto;
  top: 7vw;
  height: 80%;
  right: 25%;
  width: calc(50% + 20px);
  background-color: #2E3192;
  border-color: #2E3192;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
.sidebarleft:active {
  right: 70%;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebarleft" id="sideleft">
  <div class="lefttext">
    <div class="leftTitle">title</div>

    <div class="leftToggle">+</div>

    <div class="leftSubHead">subheading</div>

    <div class="leftInformation">
      <br />

      <div>
        <br>text
        <br />
        <form></form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the colon in your CSS: `.sidebarleftactive { ...` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gu0q2pq/1/)

Comment: haha ugh I'm a plonker. thanks!

Comment: I don't see your comment before I post my answer @George.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your CSS:

```
.sidebarleft:active {
```

To be:

```
.sidebarleftactive {
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/npgug376/